# Using blocks in multiple regions

Tags: blocks

In one demo projects I have found that I need to place same block in two different regions. 
I have the knowledge that one block can be placed to one region only. 
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module you can achieve your required feature.

This module will help you to place all your blocks in multiple regions on same or multiple page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it [module_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7.x)

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'block_machinename');
print render($block['content']); in tpl file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the multiblock module (http://dgo.to/multiblock) - D7